# @font-face não funciona no Firefox, mas no IE e no Chrome funcionam

Tags: html, css, firefox

Sempre uso `@font-face` nos meus projetos e nunca tive esse problema.

Tenho duvidas se tem algum problema com meu CSS.

O `@font-face` não esta funcionando no Firefox.

Meu código esta assim.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts.css">
```

O CSS da `@font-face` está na pasta `fonts`

```
   @font-face {
    font-family: 'futura_mdcn_btmedium';
    src: url('../fonts/futura_medium/futura_mdcn_bt_medium-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/futura_medium/futura_mdcn_bt_medium-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/futura_medium/futura_mdcn_bt_medium-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/futura_medium/futura_mdcn_bt_medium-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/futura_medium/futura_mdcn_bt_medium-webfont.svg#futura_mdcn_btmedium') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

E no meu estilo CSS está assim:

```
  p{
    font-family:'futura_mdcn_btmedium' Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;    
        }
    body{
    font-family:'futura_mdcn_btmedium' Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;        
    }
```

Eu tenho uma pasta chamada `fonts` e dentro desta pasta contém uma subpasta `futura_medium` lá estão todos os arquivos woff/ttf/svg etc.

Será que eu esqueci de algo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qual versão do Firefox usa?

Talvez ele não esta encontrando sua pasta, tente colocar mais um '../' na frente.

E está faltando uma virgula ali no seu codigo, depois do nome da sua font, antes de 'Arial'.

Tentou algum hack?
Esse site aqui tem uns hack do FF, de uma olhada quem sabe ajude.
http://browserhacks.com/

Comment: Jefferson Alison, Resolvido jamais imaginei que seria uma coisa besta um erro primário da minha parte, ignorei a vírgula por que testei em vários navegadores Chrome, Ie, rock melt, Safary, Opera e todos estavam normal justo no firefox aconteceu isso. Agradeço a ajuda

Comment: É ja fiquei horas e horas procurando onde estava faltando a virgula ou ponto e virgula.. hehe, faz parte amigo.

Answer (score 0):

Algumas sugestões:

-Tem certeza de que vc não tenha algum plugin que altera as paginas no Firefox.(isso ja aconteceu comigo)

-Experimente outras formas de informar o local, usando "~/" no lugar de ".../".

Answer (score 0):

Você observou o console de erros?
Normalmente o problema com fonts no firefox tem a ver com a falta de declaraçao do MimeType ou CORS.

```
// Declara MimeType
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff

// Permite servir fonte para outros dominios
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```