# (ASP MVC) Glyphicons Bootstrap não funcionam no Firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-3, firefox, bootstrap-glyphicons

Tenho uma aplicação ASP MVC 5 onde uso o Bootstrap que vem junto, porem, tanto no debug quando na publicação, os ícones do Bootstrap (glyphicons) não está sendo carregados, vide imagem:

[image: ícones quebrados]

Estou usando a versão do Bootstrap v3.3.7 no bundle do projeto.

Em todos os outros navegadores, funciona perfeitamente, somente no Firefox que não funciona.

Agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

**EDIT 1:**

Inspecionando no Console, me é retornado o erro abaixo:

```
glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

(isso em ambos os navegadores, inclusive naqueles onde os ícones funcionam);

indo na pasta correspondente, o arquivo .woff2 está lá ! Tentei remover ele e funciona, porém, quando outra instancia do Firefox abre, o arquivo volta e os ícones somem de novo.

Comment: 1. Algum erro no console? 2. Os arquivos estão sendo carregados corretamente? 3. Cache do browser foi "limpo"? 4. O resto do bootstrap funciona normal?

Comment: Talvez seja a falta do `../`, leia: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3458/3635, de qualquer forma olhe o console (aperte F12) deve ter alguma mensagem de erro, pode ser até CORS.

Comment: Tentou ajustar como eu falei? Posta o seu HTML e seu CSS.